# Return the index of a div inside ng-repeat to use in jQuery ui droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat looping through a bunch of different fries.

```
<div class="normal-fries">
    <div ng-repeat="fry in normalFries">
      <div class="normal-fry">
        <h3>{{ fry.name }}</h3>
        <p>Energy: {{ fry.energy }}</p>
        <p>Protein: {{ fry.protein }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have created a draggable method for the normal-fry

```
$(".normal-fry").draggable({
    addClasses: false,
  });
```

I'm trying to return the index of the fry (div) that is dropped so that i can access information about that fry within jQuery.

```
$(".normal-plate").droppable({
    accept: ".normal-fry",
    drop:function(event, ui){
      console.log($(this).index());
    }
  });
```

However I can't work out how to get the index of the dropped div. I've tried,

```
$(this).index():
```

and

```
$((ui.draggable).index());
```

and variations of the two. However I can't work it out.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably wouldn't have this problem if you used angular directive for this.

Comment: create plunker or fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You could expose the `$index` property inside your view onto a `data-` attribute and access it through jQuery in your `drop` handler.

```
<div ng-repeat="fry in normalFries">
  <div class="normal-fry" data-idx="$index">
    <h3>{{ fry.name }}</h3>
    <p>Energy: {{ fry.energy }}</p>
    <p>Protein: {{ fry.protein }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, I would recommend you go the Angular way and disregard from jQuery as much as you can. That's not to say jQuery doesn't have its use cases, but mixing and matching it with Angular is not one of them (imho).

- [angular-dragdrop](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop)
- [angular-drag-and-drop-lists](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists)
- [ngDraggable](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable)